# Angular filter exactly on object key

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a small angular app like so:

**html**

```
<body ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:1">
      <span>{{ user.username }}, {{ user.id }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    {"id":1,"username":"simon",},
    {"id":8,"username":"betty",},
    {"id":14,"username":"archie",},
    {"id":3,"username":"jumbo1"},
  ]
}
```

**output**

```
simon, 1
archie, 14
jumbo1, 3
```

What I want to do is filter an *exact* match for filter argument AND filter on the id field ONLY.

Basically, I want the output to be:

**output**

```
simon, 1
```

I am using Angular 1.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [exact filter in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242520/exact-filter-in-angular)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

In Angular 1.1.3 or newer you can use the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{'id':  1}:true">
```

`{'id':  1}` says to only compare with the field `id`.  That gets you:

```
simon, 1
archie, 14
```

`:true` says "exact match" resulting in:

```
simon, 1
```

Here's that working:  http://jsfiddle.net/AM95H/

**To filter against a list of values**, if you have the list in a scope variable, I'd add a custom filter to your JS file:

```
$scope.filterValues = [1,8];
$scope.myFilter = function(value) {
   return ($scope.filterValues.indexOf(value.id) !== -1);
};
```

Used like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users |  filter: myFilter">
```

**To filter against a parameter list** we'll create our own filter.  In this case we'll get called once with all the input values to test rather than once per value.

So the first parameter we'll receive is the array of input values (users in your case) and the second parameter will be the parameter we pass in ([1,8]).  We'll then create an output array and add (push) any items in the input stream that match one of the `filterValues`.  And return the output array.

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function () {  
   return function(inputs,filterValues) {
      var output = [];
      angular.forEach(inputs, function (input) {
        if (filterValues.indexOf(input.id) !== -1)
            output.push(input);
       });
       return output;
   };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users |  myFilter:[1,8]">
```

Here's an example of this:  http://jsfiddle.net/AM95H/2/

Comment: Prefect answer. I will accept. as an extension of that, if I want the filter argument to be a list of integers, is that possible? I tried `filter:{'id':  [1,8]}` but that doesn't work :(

Comment: I'd use a custom filter to have multiple valid exact match options.  I updated with that.

Comment: One more thing - what happens if I need to pass `filterValues` to the filter as a variable?

Comment: Updated with that- it's a little more complicated but is a nice general purpose solution.

Comment: can I know how to assign the values to a variable like **filterValues** @DarwinTech

Answer (score 6):

Based on `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter`

Filter on the Template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:id:true">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Filter on the Controller (with $param)

```
$scope.friendObj = $filter('filter')(data.friends, { id: parseInt($stateParams.friendId) }, true)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the key (property) of object in filter, on which you want to apply filter:

```
//Suppose Object
var users = [{
  "firstname": "RAM",
  "lastname": "KUMAR",
  "Address": "HOUSE NO-1, Example Street, Example Town"
  },
  {
  "firstname": "SHAM",
  "lastname": "RAJ K",
  "Address": "HOUSE NO-1, Example Street, Example Town"
}]
```

**But you want to apply filter only on firstname**

```
<input type = "text" ng-model = "f_n_model"/>
<div ng-repeat="user in users| filter:{ firstname: f_n_model}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can help

```
var rateSelected = $filter('filter')($scope.GradeList, function (obj) {
                        if(obj.GradeId == $scope.contractor_emp.save_modal_data.GradeId)
                        return obj;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<tr class="text"
*ngFor="let resource of myProjectsList |searchByKeyPipe: projectNameFilter: 
'projectName'| searchByKeyPipe: projectIdFilter : 'projectRefNo' | 
 searchByKeyPipe: dueDateFilter : 'dueOn'| searchByKeyPipe: ownerFilter : 
 'projectOwnerName' trackBy :trackByNameFunc">
```

JS

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "searchByKeyPipe",
  pure: false // marking this pipe as stateful pipe
})
export class SearchByKeyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, filter: any, key: any) {
    return items.filter(item => {
      if (filter == "" || filter == "-1") {
        return true;
      } else {
        var self = this;
        return function() {
              return item[key]
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) > -1
                ? true
                : false;
            })();
      }
    });
  }
```

By this way you can have multiple input box for keys and they will search on the particular key.