# Filter JSON data on init

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-filter

This is my JSON object:

```
{
Stores: [
{
    Name: "Store #1",
    DealerType: "Office"
},
{
    Name: "Store #2",
    DealerType: "Office"
},
{
    Name: "Store #3",
    DealerType: "Office"
},
{
    Name: "Store #4",
    DealerType: "Headquater"
},
]
}
```

This is my view:

```
<select id="dealerType">
     <option value="">All</option>
     <option value="Office">Office</option>
     <option value="Headquater">Headquaters</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="store in stores | filter:dealerType">{{store.Name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I want to only show the one store with `DealerType: "Headquater"` on pageload and still be able to use the filter functionality from the `<select>`-element

I have tried to change the `ng-repeat` to: `ng-repeat="store in stores | filter:{DealerType: 'Headquater'} | filter:dealerType"`.
This does filter by the DealerType, but will not be changed when I update the "dealerType" select.

Comment: When intializing set dealerType='Headquater'

Comment: You would need to set an ng-model for the select to be able to set it's selection as a filter. Also a typo in `Stores` casing issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/vQz9Y1?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular filter exactly on object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292638/angular-filter-exactly-on-object-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/fuwaki/1/edit

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
      <select id="dealerType" ng-model="dealerType">
     <option value="">All</option>
     <option value="Office">Office</option>
     <option value="Headquater">Headquaters</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="store in stores | filter:dealerType">{{store.Name}}  | {{store.DealerType}}</li>
</ul>
    </div>
    </div>


var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope){

   $scope.stores= [{
     Name: "Store #1",
     DealerType: "Office"
 }, {
     Name: "Store #2",
     DealerType: "Office"
 }, {
     Name: "Store #3",
     DealerType: "Office"
 }, {
     Name: "Store #4",
     DealerType: "Headquater"
 } ];

$scope.dealerType = 'Headquater'
});
```

Comment: That did it!All I had to do, was add `$scope.dealerType = "Headquater"` to my excisting code, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

### Two things:

#### Use ng-model

Make sure you set the select to be part of the model,

```
<select ng-model="dealerType">...</select>
```

#### Filter expression

Use the appropriate filter expression to target your property to the model defined above.

```
<li ng-repeat="store in stores | filter:{'DealerType': dealerType}:true">{{store.Name}}</li>
```

Check out this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292638/angular-filter-exactly-on-object-key).

And here is a [working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UT9nEsQDwEZLqNw49lWH?p=preview).