# angular filter in order by letter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am pretty new to angular. I am trying to add a filter parameter to my controller that will filter a search by every letter in a word, in order of letter. So imagine my data contained the following words: horses, oranges, terminator, Motorola, floral, orthopedic. When I searched for "or" in my search engine, all words would appear in the result because they all contain "or." Instead, I'd want a filter that filters my data in strict order of letter so I would only get "oranges" and "orthopedic"

This is my current filter in my controller:

```
$scope.activateFilter = function(textBoxValue) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    if ( textBoxValue=="") {
      $scope.pages = FacebookPage.userPages;
    } else {
      $scope.pages=$filter('filter')($scope.pages,{name:textBoxValue});
    }
  });
};
```

This is the HTML for the filtering in case it helps:

```
<div id="searchEngineController" ng-controller="SearchEngineController">
    <ul class="rig">
        <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
            <a ng-click="pageClick($index)">
                <img src= "{{page.image}}" class="img-responsive img-circle" height="140" width="240">
                <p style="font-size:25px; text-align:center">{{page.name}}<p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my JS function:

```
 pagesSearchBar.pageValueDidChange = function(value) {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('searchEngineController')).scope().activateFilter(value);
 };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-inventing the wheel. Checkout angular build-in filter for ng-repeat

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<li ng-repeat="page in pages | filter:x">
```

Reading your code more thoroughly I think you have some misunderstanding of angular logic there as well. For example, you don't need extra function to detect search change and then getting the scope from dom. You could simply do:

```
<input type="text" name="search" ng-change="activateFilter(this.value)">
```

Something like that

**UPDATE**

So If I understand correctly now, you will want to display only one result for a filter. You could achieve that by somehow **combining the filter with limitTo** (no time to fiddle around now)

Or even as a temporary solution use css:

```
.list.filtered .class-of-item {display:none;}
.list.filtered .class-of-item:first-child {display:block;}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, now I understand, so you want to use strict filtering in the way that only items starting with the search phrase show up. Angular is ready for that too, check below snippet

```js
angular.module('filterApp',[]);

angular.module('filterApp').controller('MainCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.items = ['Orange','Orangutan','Words','Orchid'];
  $scope.customComparator = function(actual, expected){
    return (actual.toLowerCase().indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="filterApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:'or':customComparator">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comparator reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: this solution would not filter every letter in order (Horses would still appear in my search results if I typed "or" in the search box), and is not applicable to my application structure (reason for which I am having to re-invent the wheel)

Comment: @jgozaI dont know what you mean by "every letter in order". If you have any special requirements why not to use angular's filter, you need to explain them well in your questions and then we can help

Comment: I edited my previous comment to better explain what I mean by "every letter in order," although I already explained it in my question. When I write "or" only "Oranges" should appear, not "Horses"

Comment: @jgozal ok I see, so you want the same functionality like the angular's filter, but only return the first result?

Comment: Not exactly the first result.  Imagine my data contained the following words: horses, oranges, terminator, Motorola, floral,  orthopedic. When I searched for "or" in my search engine, all words would appear in the result because they all contain "or." Instead, I'd want a filter that filters my data in strict order of letter so I would only get "oranges" and "orthopedic"

Comment: @jgozal I think I know what you mean now, I updated the answer

Comment: I think we're really close. So since my filter is in my controller I did something slightly different.  I copied your customComparator function to a variable in my controller as var filter_letter_comparator = .... Then in the same controller, I added a third comparator argument like this: $scope.pages=$filter('filter')($scope.pages,{name:textBoxValue},filter_letter_comparator());  This is still not working though, do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @jgozal I am not entirely sure if that is the correct way to write that - for some reason you are still trying to avoid the goods of angular, but just on quick glance on that line of code, you should supply the coparator without brackets - `$scope.pages=$filter('filter')($scope.pages,{name:textBoxValue},filter_letter_co‌​mparator)` because angular is supplying the arguments.

Comment: trust me - I wish I could do everything in the html but I really can't. I had tried it without the parenthesis too and it didn't work :( Frustrating because it seems like your comparator function would get the job done

Comment: I'm debugging. It looks like the variable definition in the controller is preventing the browser from getting to the controller in some way. Let's see if I can get it fixed.

Comment: Fixed it! It was a small syntax error (I forgot to close the comparator function}. It works perfectly. Thanks you so much!

Comment: aha! I think I did now - new to stackoverflow

Comment: Update 2 worked perfectly for me. Very elegant solution. Thank you @Tom

Answer (score 1):

Use something like below :

```
<input type="search" data-ng-model="searchName">
<li ng-repeat="list in lists | filter:searchName">{{list}}</li>
```

This filter is already provided by angular.js which itself is very powerful and quite robust.

I have made this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2wVByMtKbNMoTjqf4I3o?p=preview) which has lot more features. You might find this helpful.

Comment: hey Vaibhav, thanks for this. Unfortunately, my app structure requires that I create my filter in my controller. The solution that you suggest would still not filter every letter in order though (Horses would still appear in my search results if I typed "or" in the search box)

Comment: Did you look at this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242520/exact-filter-in-angular

Comment: I'm looking over it but it doesn't seem like it would solve my problem. I'm not looking for an exact filter. With an exact filter, I would have to type "oranges" in order to find the result "oranges." I'd like to be able to type "or" and get "oranges" in my result but not "horses"

Answer (score 1):

There a [filter in AngularJS named 'filter'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) that can make your life a lot easier in lesser code.

You can fine tune it to perform search on all fields in the object or you can restrict the search on some specific fields.

Copy pasting example from the link mentioned above:-

```
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
<label>Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"></label><br>
<label>Equality <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"></label><br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kumar Sambhav - I am using filter from angular, but in my controller (I can't use it in my html due to the way my application is structured). Even if I could use filter in html, I don't think your solution solves my problem. I am not looking for a normal filter (because then 'horses' will be shown in my results when I search for "or"), and I am not looking for a strict/exact filter (because then I would have to type "oranges in order to get "oranges" in my result). I would like to be able to search for "or" and only get words that start with "or" like "oranges" and "orthopedic"

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.pages=$filter('filter')($scope.pages,{name:textBoxValue},true);
```

This above line will change it

```
$scope.pages = $filter('filter')($scope.pages,function(index, value){
 return value === textBoxValue;
},true);
```

Comment: this makes sense but it not working for some reason :(