# Angular filter by array that contains search criteria

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Does the built in Angular "filter" support filtering an array in the sense that "filter where array contains "

Such as follows:

```
$scope.currentFilter = "Allentown";

$scope.users = [{
   name: "user1", 
   locations: [
      { name: "New York", ... },
      { name: "Allentown", ... },
      { name: "Anderson", ... },
   ]

}, ... ];

<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter : { locations: { name: currentFilter } }"></div>
```

In other words I'm looking to filter to only users with a "locations" array that CONTAINS a location that matches the string by name.

If not, how can I accomplish this with a custom filter?

Comment: So what is the problem? you code works as you described.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242520/exact-filter-in-angular

Comment: As @dfsq mentioned, works as you describe.

Comment: you can write custom filter, here is little example on your data http://jsfiddle.net/xgnpkb35/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet works as is since [Angular 1.2.13](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1213-romantic-transclusion-2014-02-14). In case you're using an older version (tested on 1.0.1) and don't need to reuse your filtering routine across controllers (in which case you should declare a proper filter), you can pass the built-in [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) a predicate function :

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter : hasLocation">{{user.name}}</div>
```

And write something like this :

```
$scope.currentFilter = "Allentown";

$scope.hasLocation = function(value, index, array) {
    return value.locations.some(function(location) {
       return location.name == $scope.currentFilter;
    });
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32a55kqv/1/).