# Better Searching With Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have built an angular app which searches through a load of objects.

The problem is that the search filters match any part of the string returning irrelevant searches. 
for example.
If I search the name Steve
the results will bring up both steve , eve and steven. I want the search results to return steve and steven.
Plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/awN5ZxIpZ3fJJUkD5k6Y
Code

```
<input id="search-input" ng-model="searchTerm" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<ul class="search-ul">

    <li class="search-list"  ng-if="searchTerm.length > 2" ng-repeat="item in SearchItems| filter:searchTerm">
         <div class="button-wrap">
        <a href="" ng-click="openLinkSearch(item.url)"><img class="icon" src="{{item.image}}" /></a>
    </div>
       <span class="text">{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/awN5ZxIpZ3fJJUkD5k6Y If you search eve steve is still there and if you search bus they both display.

Comment: Here you go. https://plnkr.co/edit/bvon6vGuRdZgs3fAAy22?p=info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exact filter in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242520/exact-filter-in-angular)

Comment: What is your expectation when you search "eve" ?

Comment: I know that angular's defaults behavior is to return steve. I dont want that thought. I dont want it to find matches within the words them selfs

Comment: @awalter, check the plunkr i sent.

Answer (score 2):

Reproducing with an object that only has a name field, I get results as expected ('steve' and 'steven' only). This suggests that it is matching on something other than the name field.

If you want your filter to ONLY use the `item.name` field then use the following:

```
<li class="search-list"  ng-if="searchTerm.length > 2" ng-repeat="item in SearchItems| filter:{name:searchTerm}">
```

Comment: This would be nice. But it does not work. Is this for angularJS 1 or 2

Comment: AngularJS 1, testing it on 1.5 specifically but it has worked that way for quite a few versions.

Comment: could you make a plunkr so I can see it in action?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Angular material.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

For strict search you have to tag the object property to search field.

For example to filter name
`<input ng-model="searchTerm.name"></label>
<label>Equality <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"></label><br>`

Also try setting strict

```
ng-repeat="item in SearchItems| filter:searchTerm:strict"
```

Comment: Doesn't the strict search require you to use the full word? I want people to be able to start searching and the relevant info to display. But I want the filter to not pickup matches that appear within words. For example if you search eve you will see steve, because steve ends in eve.

Comment: Thanks walter .I tried adding "evening" to the plunker example and searched for Steve, but it didn't retrieved evening as you mentioned in question. Are you sure your question is correct ?