# Angular repeat filter with exact match

Tags: angularjs

I need to do an exact match filter, but having some trouble getting it to work.

[I have set up a jsfiddle for this issue](https://jsfiddle.net/tb21uowt/) that works fine, until I add in the ":true" on this line.

```
  <li ng-repeat="worktime in worktimes  = (worktimes | filter:{ employeeId : employeeFilter }:true)">{{worktime.customerName}}</li>
```

It then doesn't work anymore. What am I doing wrong?

In my app I have an issue that I hope has the same cause.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480526/angularjs-filter-exact-match?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML renders like below on View

```
<select ng-model="employeeFilter" style="width: 100px;" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="? string: ?"></option>
    <option value="7" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Jamie</option>
    <option value="37" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Anne</option>
    <option value="8" class="ng-scope ng-binding">James</option>
</select>
```

In which value of `employeeFilter` means the option value of select box which are present in `""` like `value="7"` for Jamie.

You are mentioning `true` in your filter, that means you're making strongly type check.

In this case `7==="7"` is not true. Therefore you need to `parse` the variable to `integer` before filtering, after parsing `"7"` will become `7` you will get expected result like `7===7` //will become true

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="employeeFilter" style="width: 100px;">
           <option data-ng-repeat="employee in employeesFilterList" value="{{employee.id}}">{{employee.username}}</option>
      </select>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.doParseInt = function(val){
    if(val && val != "")
    return parseInt(val)
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tb21uowt/3/)

This could be helpful to you. Thanks.

Comment: @iKode does it helped?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="worktime in worktimes | filter: {'employeeId': employeeFilter} : true ">{{worktime.customerName}}</li>
```

this will work