# Angular.js filter by exact values (strict equality)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following html code

```
  <ul ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: { age: '2' } | orderBy: 'name' ">
   <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Here is my $scope variable

```
 $scope.friends = [
{ name: "Peter",   age: 2 },
{ name: "Pablo",   age: 55 },
{ name: "Linda",   age: 20 },
{ name: "Marta",   age: 37 },
{ name: "Othello", age: 20 },
{ name: "Markus",  age: 32 }
];
```

It returns

```
Linda
Markus
Othello
Peter
```

How the comparison work in ng filter and How do i get friend having age 2 only

```
Peter
```

Comment: In order to have an exact match for your filter you will have to write down a custom filter.Refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480526/angularjs-filter-exact-match

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of Angular 1.2, you just need to add the strict parameter (true) to the filter so that it looks for an exact match, and pass `2` as a number instead of a string: `filter:{age:2}:true`

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.friends = [
    {name: "Peter",   age: 2 },
    {name: "Pablo",   age: 55},
    {name: "Linda",   age: 20},
    {name: "Marta",   age: 37},
    {name: "Othello", age: 20},
    {name: "Markus",  age: 32}
  ]; 
})
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{age:2}:true | orderBy: 'name' ">
   <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/w4L9zswo/ .I tried what you said but it's not working.

Comment: i edited the comment actaully it is including I in the link :-)

Comment: Thanks i solved it actually there is the version problem it will not work in 1.0.x but it is working in 1.2.x :-)

Comment: @squiroid was just about to tell ya =D Answer updated to include version.

Comment: @OP m59 answer is awesome but keep in mind the verion you are using :-)

Answer (score 1):

Added directive to convert the model value to number workded for me after setting strict parameter (true).

```
myApp.directive('convertNumber', [function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return parseInt(value, 10);
      });

      ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        if (value != null) {
          return value.toString();
        };
      });      
    }
  }
}]);
```