# Angular NG-Repeat - Built In Filter Not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing an app using Angular 1.5.5.  I'm trying to filter an array of Location objects by ID.  The Locations array has 10 objects in it.  The filter is returning 2 objects instead of the of the one:

Locations Array:
[image]

My html template looks like:

```
                        <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="location in offerings.Locations | filter : {'ID':event.LocationID}">
                        {{location.Name}}<br />
                        {{location.Address}}, {{location.City}}, {{location.State}} {{location.Zip}}<br />
                        Loc ID = {{location.ID}} eventLocID = {{event.LocationID}}
                    </div>
```

It's returning 2 results instead of the filter where 2 = 2:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like it filter like strings, not numbers, you have got 12, because it contains 2

Comment: I think this could be some issue related to `event.LocationID` or its type.. can you provide a plunker/fiddle reproducing this?

Comment: Thanks tanmay - it looks like that is the problem.  Leguest's answer below solves that issue:
ng-repeat="location in offerings.Locations | filter : {'ID':event.LocationID} : true"

Comment: @user1231748 did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try write own filter function or use that construction:

```
  ng-repeat="location in offerings.Locations | filter : {'ID':event.LocationID} : true"
```

Also check this topic [Filter array of objects by attribute with integer value in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849580/filter-array-of-objects-by-attribute-with-integer-value-in-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.event = {"LocationID" : 2}
    $scope.locations = [
     {
     "Address": "address1",
     "city": "city1",
     "ID": 2,
     "Name": "name1",
     "State": "state1",
     "Zip": 243435
     },
     {
     "Address": "address2",
     "city": "city2",
     "ID": 3,
     "Name": "name2",
     "State": "state2",
     "Zip": 243435
     },
      {
     "Address": "address3",
     "city": "city3",
     "ID": 12,
     "Name": "name3",
     "State": "state3",
     "Zip": 243435
     }    
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                    <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="location in locations | filter:{'ID' : event.LocationID}:true">
                        {{location.Name}}<br />
                        {{location.Address}}, {{location.City}}, {{location.State}} {{location.Zip}}<br />
                        Loc ID = {{location.ID}} eventLocID = {{event.LocationID}}
                    </div>
</div>
```