# Filter nested array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a JSON feed that looks something like this:

```
[{
    "title":"Post 1",
    "categories":[1]
},{
    "title":"Post 2",
    "categories":[12,123]
},{
    "title":"Post 3",
    "categories":[123]
}]
```

and I'd like to be able to filter it by "categories" and "title", like so:

```
<select ng-model="search.categories">
    <option value="">Categories</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
</select>

<input ng-model="search.title">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:search">
        {{post.title}} - {{post.categories}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Title search works fine. But for categories a search for "1" matches "1", "12" and "123" (and similarly, "12" matches "12" and "123"). Is there a way to limit search results to the exact match? I'm assuming to do that "categories" array has to be split somehow so each ID is matched separately.

---

Another option: can I filter parent loop based on content of nested child loop? Here's the code:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:search">
        {{post.title}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="category in post.categories">
                {{category}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480526/angularjs-filter-exact-match

Comment: Not a duplicate, since he's using an object to filter and only wants one property to be checked for an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comparison function or simply `true` after another colon, to have angular only accept exact matches. Also you can use multiple filters by just adding another pipe. It should look something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter : search.categories : true | filter : search.title">
```

See more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Exact filter doesn't work as is because I'm comparing a single value to a comma separated array. If I were to search for "1", posts with "categories" set to "1,12,123" won't match.