# angularjs, filtering, returning equal results

Tags: angularjs, filter, filtering, equality

I am filtering using AngularJS. Everything works fine, but I want a filter to work differently. If "1" is searched, the result should only be "1". I would like your help regarding this issue.

```
<table ng-table ="usersTable" show-filter=true class="table table-bordered table-striped">

<tr ng-repeat="user in data">

<td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'" filter="{ 'name': 'text' }">{{user.name}}</td>

<td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'age'" filter="{ 'age': 'text' }">{{user.age}}</td>

<td data-title="'Location'" sortable="'location'" filter="{ 'location': 'text' }">{{user.location}}</td>

</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AngularJS Filter Exact Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480526/angularjs-filter-exact-match)